# Remove all but first occurrence of 2nd array item from first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array of strings. 2nd array lists over Used Words. I am trying to delete all but first occurrence of 2nd array item from first array. Code is working except it couldn't delete last 2 duplicates.

1st array storyWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically',"more","more","more"];

2nd array overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

Expected output: [ 'really',  'very',  'basically', 'more',  'more',  'more' ]

Actual output: [ 'really',  'very',  'basically',  'really',  'very',  'basically',  'more',  'more',  'more' ]

```
const storyWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically',"more","more","more"];

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

overusedWords.forEach(f=>{
  storyWords.forEach((s,i)=>{
    if(s === f){      
      if(storyWords.indexOf(s) !== storyWords.lastIndexOf(s)){  // using i in exchange of i results same
        storyWords.splice(storyWords.lastIndexOf(s),1);        
      }
    }
  })
})

console.log(storyWords);
```

Expected output: [ 'really',  'very',  'basically', 'more',  'more',  'more' ]

Actual output: [ 'really',  'very',  'basically',  'really',  'very',  'basically',  'more',  'more',  'more' ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with reduce. I am checking for two cases.
It is not in the output array or it is not in the overusedWords

```js
var storyWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically','really', 'very', 'basically',"more"]
var overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

var output = storyWords.reduce((filterWords, word) => (!filterWords.includes(word) || !overusedWords.includes(word)) ? filterWords.concat(word) : filterWords,[])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Yes it works as I wanted. Thanks a lot. Any idea about why my one was not working?

Comment: The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array. So, avoid splice() to avoid confusion while you are looping over that array.